# Autogentrated Entity models always true even custom class implemented

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using autogenerated entity model classes and than i used partial class with metadata to put validations on auto genetrated classes like below.

```
public class tblDepartmentCustom
    {

        [Key]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Department name is required")]
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    }
    [MetadataType(typeof(tblDepartmentCustom))]
    public partial class tblDepartmentMaster
    {
    }
```

The original class that was generated by entity framework is given below.

```
public partial class tblDepartmentMaster
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public tblDepartmentMaster()
        {
            this.tblDesignationMasters = new HashSet<tblDesignationMaster>();
        }


        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<tblDesignationMaster> tblDesignationMasters { get; set; }
    }
```

So the problem here is that whenever i try to validated model state it comes out to be true.below is the code.

```
@model EmployeeManager.Models.tblDepartmentCustom
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "InsertDepartment";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}<div class="col-md-4">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("InsertDepartment", "Departments", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <span class="error-class">@ViewBag.FoundError</span>
        <br />
        <label>Department Name</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DepartmentName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Add Department" />
    }
</div>
```

And the action below.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult InsertDepartment()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [ActionName("InsertDepartment")]
        public ActionResult InsertDepartmentPost()
        {

            using (PMSEntities dc = new PMSEntities())
            {

                tblDepartmentMaster dm = new tblDepartmentMaster();
                TryUpdateModel(dm);
                if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    dc.tblDepartmentMasters.Add(dm);
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                    return View("_Success");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.FoundError = "Department name is required.";
                    return View();
                }
                           }
        }
```

Comment: ModelState.IsValid-is returning always true, its not giving error when empty textbox submitted.

Comment: Make sure that the class that contains the validation attributes has the same namespace as the generated class.

Comment: they are in different folders/namespaces because EF autogenerate in root and my custom files are in models folder. And tell me where to define any other validation attribute, i have pasted all code above @JB06

Comment: In order for partial classes to work, both partials must have the same namespace. You don't have to move the actual files around your file structure, just edit the namespace of tblDepartmentCustom to match that of tblDepartmentMaster @techsolver

Comment: Thanks @JB06, it Worked.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer @techsolver

Answer (score 0):

In order for partial classes to work, both partials must have the same namespace. You don't have to move the actual files around your file structure, just edit the namespace of tblDepartmentCustom to match that of tblDepartmentMaster.